# remove arrow from extjs tooltip,

Tags: tooltip, extjs3

I want to remove this triangle from `panel`, it comes while showing `tooltip` using extjs3.

[image]

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
var tooltipHide = new Ext.ToolTip({
    anchor: 'bottom',
    target: 'summaryButton',
    anchorOffset: 0, // center the anchor on the tooltip                        
    width: 300,
    mouseOffset: [0, 25],
    autoHide: false,
    closable: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    html: '<div style="overflow:hidden;height:480px;width:300px;">' +
        mycaseSummaryData + '</div>',
});
```

I am calling `tooltip` on `mouseover` event using `tooltipHide.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `css`, In css you just need to set `background-size: 0px;`.

like below example:

```
<style>
    .x-custom-tooltip .x-tip-anchor{
        background-size: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2emo)**, I have created a demo using your code and put some modification. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Example of tooltip in ExtJS 3.4',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        padding: 10,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Summary Button',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (btn) {
                    btn.tooltipHide = new Ext.ToolTip({
                        anchor: 'bottom',
                        cls: 'x-custom-tooltip',
                        target: btn.getEl(),
                        anchorOffset: 0, // center the anchor on the tooltip
                        width: 300,
                        autoHide: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        html: '<span style="color: green;">This tooltip using showBy method and css....<span>',
                    });
                    btn.el.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                        this.tooltipHide.showBy(this.getEl(), 'tl-tr');
                    }, btn);

                    btn.el.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                        this.tooltipHide.hide();
                    }, btn);
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'tbspacer',
            height: 20
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Summary Button 2',
            listeners: {
                afterrender: function (btn) {
                    btn.tooltipHide = new Ext.ToolTip({
                        target: btn.getEl(),
                        anchorOffset: 0, // center the anchor on the tooltip
                        width: 300,
                        mouseOffset: [0, 25],
                        autoHide: false,
                        closable: false,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        html: '<span style="color: red;">This tooltip show by without css and removed anchor.<span>',
                    });
                    btn.el.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                        this.tooltipHide.show();
                    }, btn);

                    btn.el.on('mouseout', function (e) {
                        this.tooltipHide.hide();
                    }, btn);
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: how to accept? I just got option to vote.please guide

Comment: In my answer you will `right` icon. You just need to click on that.

Comment: one more thing can we fix the tooltip position, for me its not showing at fixed place . sometime more left, sometime more on to right

Comment: you can use this `this.tooltipHide.showBy(this.getEl(), 'tl-tr');`. This will always Show the tip's top-left corner anchored to the element's top-right corner [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Tip-method-showBy).